# SSRS - Ignore NULL when doing Boolean IFF expression

Tags: reporting-services

Hi guys I have a simple IFF expression

=IIF(Fields!MYCOLUMN.Value = true, "Yes", "No")

which is working fine, except other rows that have a blank or NULL in it's place are returning "No".
Is there a way to adapt my expression so that it ignores Null values? I have tried incorporating ISNOTHING but having trouble getting the syntax right.

Comment: `=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!MYCOLUMN.Value), "", IIF(Fields!MYCOLUMN.Value, "Yes", "No"))` just to illustrate how to do it using ISNOTHING. Also note there is not need to test for `= true` as that is implicitly what IIF does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IFF, IIF, or IF? If this is in the SQL query/stored proc and not the report itself, the answer below just changes to a SQL CASE statement.

Use a switch statement to define what you want displayed in the third case.

```
=Switch(
Fields!MYCOLUMN.Value = true,"Yes",
Fields!MYCOLUMN.Value = false,"No",
true,"")
```